# What does "I've been sick lately" imply?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

The sentence "I've been sick" can either mean:

-I'm still sick;

-I was sick;

Although, putting a "lately" at the end of the sentence implies what? That I am still sick, or that I was sick in a time of the past?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It implies that you  are better now.

Comment: You  can find  the  answer 
  here.       https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115198/what-does-i-have-been-sick-imply  answer  here.

Comment: @user067531 Yes, but it does imply to me that the speaker has had either an extended period of sickness or suffered a number of short periods of sickness in the recent past whereas "I've been sick" implies a single, reasonably short, period of illness or a single vomiting event which has just occurred.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with Englishmonger's answer. Having read [the link he provided](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115198/what-does-i-have-been-sick-imply), the answers are a little ambiguous, but provide extra details.

Personally, I've both heard people use that phrase—and used it myself—to indicate that they were previously sick, but are better now. Otherwise, people usually follow the statement with some clause indicating that they've still not recovered, or are *in recovery*.